# Passing list of Enum as path variable - Spring/Kotlin

Tags: spring, rest, kotlin, spring-rest

Trying to pass list of Enum values as path variable

```
@GetMapping(path = ["/days"], produces = ["application/json;charset=UTF-8"])
      @ApiOperation("Process by days of week")
      fun processByDaysOfWeek(@PathVariable day: List<DayOfWeek>): {
    ...
    }

enum class DayOfWeek {
  MONDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY;
}
```

When testing with RestAssured

```
val days = listOf(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, DayOfWeek.THURSDAY)

    RestAssured
      .given()
      .spec(spec)
      .pathParam("days", days)
      .get("/engine/workday/{days}")
      .then()
      .statusCode(200)
      .extract().`as`(JsonNode::class.java)

Request method: GET
Request URI:    http://localhost:62938/engine/workday/%3D%5B%22MONDAY%22%2C%22THURSDAY%22%5D
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    days=["MONDAY","THURSDAY"]
Headers:        Accept=*/*
                Content-Type=application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookies:        <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Body:           <none>
```

What is the best way to test this? I want the URL to look like

http://localhost:62938/engine/workday/MONDAY,THURSDAY

Answer (score 0):

You can use `joinToString` on your list.

```
assertEquals("MONDAY,THURSDAY", listOf(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, DayOfWeek.THURSDAY).joinToString(","))
```